# My percentage value is printing '0' in textbbox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, class

Problem Definition: Design a webpage which inputs student details like student id, name, gender, stream , marks
of any 3 subjects, calculate total, percentage, grade according to university rules and display.

For this program  i have made 1 class Student.cs to initialize all the variables but my display percen()is not working correctly

Student

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
   public class Student
 {
int id;
string name;
string gender;


string stream;


int[] marks;

public int[] Marks1
{
    get { return marks; }
    set { marks = value; }
}
public Student( int id,string name,string gender,string stream,int[] 
marks)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.stream = stream;
    this.marks = marks;
}
public int Id
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
}

public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}
public int[] Marks
{
    get { return marks; }
    set { marks = value; }
}
public string Gender
{
    get { return gender; }
    set { gender = value; }
}
public string Stream
{
    get { return stream; }
    set { stream = value; }
}
public string toString()
{

    return "name = "+name+"Id - "+id+"gendre = "+gender+"stream = 
"+stream+"marks - "+marks;
}

public int calc_total(int []marks)
{int arr;
      arr = marks[0] + marks[1] + marks[2];

    return arr;


}

 public int persent(int total)
 {
     int p = (total / 300) * 100;
     return p;
   }
 }
```

StudentDetails.aspx.cs file:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class StudentDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void TextBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string gender = "";
    if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        gender="Male";
    }
    else{
        gender="Female";
    }

    int id=int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    string name = TextBox2.Text; ;
   string stream=TextBox4.Text;

   int []marks=new int [3];
    marks[0]=int.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
    marks[1] = int.Parse(TextBox6.Text);
    marks[2] = int.Parse(TextBox7.Text);
    Student s = new Student(id,name,gender,stream,marks);
    s.Id = id;
    s.Name = name;
    s.Gender = gender;
    s.Marks = marks;

    int total = s.calc_total(marks);
    TextBox10.Text = total.ToString();
    int per = s.persent(total);
    TextBox8.Text = per.ToString();
    TextBox8.Text+= "%";
    }
     }
```

Comment: Since you are doing integer division, this statement `(total / 300)` is coming out 0 and then you multiply it by 100, but `0 * 100 = 0`.  What you probably meant was `(total / 3)` or if you want a double value, then you can do `(total / 3.0)`, in any event 300 is the wrong value there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just modify the code :

```
 public int persent(int total)
 {
     int p = (total * 100) / 300;
     return p;
 }
```